# How to join on multiple lists only by list index using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

To preface, I see some answers for C#, and some for Python.
Each seems to require iteration through the loops.
With as advanced as we have come with LINQ, I figure there has to be a solution out there.

I have three `ArrayList` objects in VB.net.  They are parallel in the sense that they will always have the same number of items.  They are only carrying strings, and for each of these items, there is no relationship that can be leveraged.

I would like to be able to use LINQ, preferably a `JOIN`, that would allow me to create a `List(Of StringTuple)`, where each item has three fields, each of `string`, representing each of the items in the relative position of the three `ArrayList` objects.

I understand that I could iterate through the `ArrayList` using an index and `For` or `For Each` loop.  But that would be bad for performance.  Instead I would like to join these three objects on the index value of the `ArrayList`'s themselves.  I can't find this approach anywhere, or at least one that would be a marked improvement over iterating n times over the `ArrayList`.

Notes:

I know `ArrayList` is not desirable.  This is legacy code.  I can temporarily cast into `IEnumerable` if I need to.

As an example, in my mind, I would see the join and creation as such:

```
Dim aList as ArrayList = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
Dim bList as ArrayList = {'1', '2', '3'}
Dim cList as ArrayList = {'#', '*', '!'}

Public Class StringTuple

   Public aType as String
   Public bType as String
   Public cType as String

End Class
```

(Excuse my VB.  I know how I would do this in C#.  I am asking this question partly to learn how to write the LINQ in VB.Net)

```
Dim query = From a In aList _
            Join b In bList _ 
            On (Index property?) _
            Join c In cList _ 
            On (Index property?) _
            Select New StringTuple With { .aType = a, .bType = b, .cType = c }
```

Comment: But linq is looping in the background. No performance improvement. Set a break point when you iterate query and you will see all the jumping around.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below:

data:

```
Dim aList As New ArrayList({"a", "b", "c"})
Dim bList As New ArrayList({"1", "2", "3"})
Dim cList As New ArrayList({"#", "*", "!"})
```

class:

```
Public Class StringTuple
    Public a_Type As String
    Public b_Type As String
    Public c_Type As String
End Class
```

And the Query is

```
    Dim output1 = From n1 In aList
                  Join n2 In bList On aList.IndexOf(n1) Equals bList.IndexOf(n2)
                  Join n3 In cList On bList.IndexOf(n2) Equals cList.IndexOf(n3)
                  Select New StringTuple With {.a_Type = n1, .b_Type = n2, .c_Type = n3}
```

Comment: Ok, nice.  This does look like it should work.  Let me test it in the office tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked, having to cast the IEnumerable output1 ToList.

Comment: I think @Mary might be right though.  With 10,000 items, using a for loop took 0.0040817 seconds.  Using this LINQ approach took 1.0324607 seconds